# What are the supported status values available in android-publisher APIs?

Tags: android, google-play-developer-api

I was referring the below android-publisher apis page

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/tracks

It contains status key in many examples with different values like `completed`, `inProgress`, `halted` etc

```
{
  "releases": [{
      "versionCodes": ["88"],
      "status": "completed"
  }]
}
```

I want to know what all status values are available for use and with which track they can be used, I've looked everywhere but didn't find relevant documentation around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is extremely late, but I found this https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/edits/tracks#resource in the grid list it tells the different options

- completed
- draft
- halted
- inProgress